# Unable to focus on nearby objects

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm having difficulties with the Camera2 API's in regards to autofocus.  I am trying to snap pictures of objects at about 6-8" range, specifically, a bank check, however, until the object is at approximately 12" range, the text on the check is very blurry and it doesn't seem that the device's autofocus is working properly.  When I use the device's built-in Camera application, I don't have this issue at all.

The blurriness is present in both the preview and captured still image.

I'm using code from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic , and have been playing with all of the autofocus settings I can think to try, and so far none have worked.

This is on a Samsung Galaxy S5.  Unfortunately I don't have any other Android 5 devices to try it out on right now.

How can I achieve smooth focus on such items similar to the native Camera app?

Comment: Some strange behavior...  If I block the camera lens when I hit the button to take a picture, the flash will activate because the AE is detecting low-light conditions... if I unblock the camera prior to this operation finishing, the focus is PERFECT on the check when returning to preview mode.  Moving the camera closer or nearer at that point still results in blurriness.  Still, I'm puzzles as to how to automatically achieve this focus continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I believe I have the reason why this isn't working on the S5 based on some investigation as to how the default camera app code works as of API 22.  It seems that as of right now, my device is considered as legacy (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL).

The default Android camera code falls back on the deprecated camera APIs when the device has anything less than INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL.  To me, this seems like some form of admission that Camera2 isn't quite ready for applications that must stably support a large base of devices.  The old Camera API works perfectly, I was just trying to go with the recommendation of using Camera2 for new applications.

For anyone that comes across this in the future, check the status out of OneCamera - that looks like the direction the default camera is angling and it seems like the old PhotoModule code will eventually be deprecated or just wrap calls to OneCamera.  For clarification... OneCamera is some code that currently seems to only exist within the Android camera app.  This is located at: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git .  I was using the Lollipop release branch at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you locking AF by issuing an AF_TRIGGER_START before taking the final image?  Which AF modes did you try to use?

There is a minimum focus distance that the camera can succesfully focus at, but that's on the range of 10cm.

Comment: I am locking AF prior to the final image.  I would like to say I tried "all" AF modes (I am not near my laptop at the moment to list them all, but I looked at the Android SDK and methodically tried every single one), and various AE settings as well with no luck.  I know the settings are "working" because when I turn off AE, I don't get a flash in low light situations where I do when the setting is CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH.

I'm starting to dig into this some more and seeing how the default Camera app actually works. Hopefully that will help me gain some insight here.